# what happens to the remote history if I merge local branch to main

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

I have a remote branch (main), and I have 2 local branches (main and my_feature).

I am working on "my_feature" branch, and when I finished I want to merge it into "master".

What happens to the remote "main" history for all other developers that don't have "my_feature" branch? They will see my local branch?

Answer (score 2):

When you merge your local "my_feature" branch into your local "master" branch, and then push the updated "master" branch to the remote "main", other developers who have pulled the "main" branch will not see your local "my_feature" branch. Instead, they will only see the changes made in "my_feature" as part of the new history of the "main" branch. Your local "my_feature" branch will still exist on your machine, but will not be reflected on the remote repository or other developers' machines.

Answer (score 2):

The other users are not going to see your local my_feature branch unless you push it explicitly to the remote repository.

Once my_feature is merged into main and main will be pushed to remote repo the other users are going to see my_feature's commits history as part of the main-branch' commits history.

As unwanted advice, consider to have a branching/PR-reviewing strategy agreed by you and the repository's other users. In my own experience code which is not reviewed, devs who work alone and no testing is very painful in the end (both for code and for devs growth)

Answer (score 1):

The quick and strict answer to your question is: Nothing happens to remote history if you merge a local branch unless your push it.

One of the main differences between git and other source control systems is that you developers get to decide whether others see changes or not. You have local and remote versioning.
If you merge your branch `my_feature` into your local `main/master` branch other developers never get to see your changes unless you push (publish) these changes. If it is your goal to experiment with something, you don't have to push and never have to share those changes with others. You can still reset your personal local copy of `main` back to `remotes/origin/main` if your experiment goes wrong.
If you decide that you want to publish your changes, other developers will see the same commits as you do locally. Merges usually (there are options such as `--no-ff` that don't) generate a merge commit saying something like "Merge branch 'my_feature' into main" and containing all the usual commit information like author etc..
The branch `my_feature`, however, is only published if you explicitly push it with e.g. `git push --set-upstream origin my_features`. Branches are nothing more than pointers (or names) to commits. That is very different compared to other versioning system.

From your question it is obvious that you are new to git. I recommend reading official git documentation and learning with tools such as https://learngitbranching.js.org/. Hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't understand one thing: you wrote that the "Merges usually (there are options such as --no-ff that don't) generate a merge commit saying something like "Merge branch 'my_feature' into main"". This is the fact I asked in the first question: other developers won't read this message, cause they do not have my local branch.

Comment: Sorry, now I am a bit confused and not sure if I understand you correctly: If you push, there will usually be a merge commit containing your local branche name. People can read that name, even if they don't have your branch. Again: Branches are pointers to commits and give names to commits or collections of commits if you like. Nothing more is a branch. So you´re not hiding much from others, if you push your merge. Does that make it clear? If not, why not make a play project and try it yourself?

Comment: thanks, you have been clear. Other developers can see in the history the "merge" message, even If they don't have my local branch.

Comment: If you decide to push, yes.